# Copying directory structure using wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3, heat

So I have a huge file structure which I want the installer, I am building using wix, to copy on the client location.  Currently I am typing it out like:

```
<Directory Id="xyz" Name = "abc FileSource = "sdfsdf">
    <Component Id="asdas" Guid="asdasd">
        <File Id = "asdfgrs" Name="name" />
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

As the number of files have increased I would like this to be done in an automated way. Using heat I am able to generate:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="weqw">
   <Component Id="2132312" Directory="Some random string (cause of concern>" Guid="asdasd">
        <File Id="sdqwdqwd> keyPath="yes" Source = "Correct source path" />
    </Component>
<ComponentGroup>
```

My concern is that due to the presence of some random string in Directory field of Component generated by heat, I wont get the directory structure replicated. Is this true? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `heat /?` output:

```
-dr      directory reference to root directories (cannot contains spaces 
         e.g. -dr MyAppDirRef)
```

If you use heat to recursively harvest a directory structure, then the `-dr` switch will set the ID of the root target folder. This ID should match the ID of a `Directory` element you have specified elsewhere in your wxs files.

For the harvested subfolders, heat will still generate a random ID. A given ID will appear multiple times in the generated XML file:

1. In the `Directory` element generated by heat for that subfolder, as the `Id` attribute.
2. In the `Component` elements associated with that folder, As the `Directory` attribute.

The ID is only used to link `Component` elements to `Directory` elements. **It is not the folder name as it appears after installation.** It is only used as a key in the Windows Installer database.